# Request module return unicode characters

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to get normal response using *request* module in node.js
and i've got problem to get response from amazon.com as normal string
i dont know why, but ive got problem only with amazon.com (eg. amazon.it, amazon.co.uk does return normal string).

```
const request = require('request');

request.get(
    { 
        uri: 'https://www.amazon.com',
        encoding: 'utf-8'
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body)
});
```

The code above return something like:
 b��╝��W>�S�Uk��z�=8~r����9|r|P^?}p o╗��l���ߋ�t`ޜ^]��n!��
���U�>>�@�w-z�.��O�����Oo��������y�����g�N�/��{����_>���鳟�=s���w?�z��_W)i؃�
��;�*��2��9<�0ٷ8����<=�ϱ��ղ��3�=(�"�ԯ�; �3��=�8�2;=���28����#+,3��0"�+Ǳ �)�2�<*�
 ���7�(W?�8�9\?�)#'���";�ķ���ܣ�ѽ����|�8   ��╚ ��'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response returned by Amazon is gzipped. You have to provide the `gzip` option to your request.

```
const request = require('request');

request.get(
    {
        uri: 'https://www.amazon.com',
        gzip: true,
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body)
});
```